# How do I prevent Firefox from scrolling nested content to the top when printing

Tags: html, css, firefox, scroll, printing

Here's some code that illustrates the problem:

```
<style>
    .container {
        background: green;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .inner {
        background: blue;
        color: white;

        height: 50px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I print the resulting web page in Chrome, it maintains the scroll position of the inner div. But when I do the same in Firefox, it always scrolls the inner div to the top.

Is this an issue with Firefox? Is there a way for me to maintain the scroll position?